# Custom keyboard shortcut to lauch a terminal and run a command in Unity

Tags: unity, command-line, shortcut-keys

I know this should be the simplest thing, but coming up empty. ;-(

I would like to create a keyboard shortcut `ctrl-alt-P` that opens a terminal window and runs a `ping` command:

`ping -c 4 somefixeddomain.com`

[Useful for quickly checking whether my internet connection is actually working.]

I have attempted to do this (in Unity, Ubuntu v11.10) using:

`Settings > Keyboard > Custom Shortcuts`

filling in all the obvious stuff, but no luck. All ideas welcome.

Comment: Hi have you tried doing that from terminal ? If not then try this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts hope that helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**For Ubuntu 11.10 (Unity)**

1. Go to `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts`.
2. Add a new shortcut by pressing the `+` button.
3. Choose a name for your shortcut, and in the 'Command' field, enter

   ```
   gnome-terminal -e "ping -c4 [your domain here]"
   ```
4. Assign your shortcut key combination by selecting the shortcut and pressing the combination you desire (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).

Comment: `gnome-terminal`. Exactly what I needed. Thanks, mucho! ;-)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on 19.04, Disco Dingo. Is there any method for newer versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

#### For Lubuntu 20.04

1. Go to `Start button on taskbar` **>** `Preferences` **>** `LXQt settings` **>** `Shortcut Keys`
2. Press <kbd>Add</kbd> key to add new shortcut keys
3. Click on `Shortcut:` and press your shortcut keys
4. Write a description to the current shortcut keys
5. Choose the type of running: `Command` or `DBus message`
6. After implementing the running method press <kbd>Ok</kbd>

Comment: There exists no such setting.