# Keyboard shortcut to a sudo-script

Tags: shortcut-keys, bash, sudo

How do I create a keyboard shortcut to a script that needs sudo privileges?
I tried to create shortcuts via Ubuntu Keyboard Settings GUI to scripts

> "sh script.sh"
>   "sudo sh script.sh"

They don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116052/custom-keyboard-shortcut-to-lauch-a-terminal-and-run-a-command-in-unity

Comment: also when calling scripts you need to use bash scriptname, than sh scriptname

Comment: This is incorrect. You only need to run a script with `bash` if it uses the extended functionality `bash` provides. When a script has a `.sh` extension, that indicates (by convention) that it can be run by the system's default `sh`, even if that is not `bash`. (Most scripts with no extension can be run by `sh` too--if a script needs `bash`, then its documentation should indicate this, or it should have a [hashbang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang) at the top for it, which if you're manually invoking `sh` or `bash` you can check first.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sudo requires a terminal to get the password from. Use gksudo instead; it asks for the password via a gui dialog box.

```
gksudo -- script
```

Comment: `gksudo` is not recommended anymore.(http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default). I suggest to use `pkexec ./script`

Answer (score 3):

`gksudo` is not recommended anymore.(see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default))

Use `pkexec ./script`. By default, it will pop up a screen to enter credentials. See its man page for more info.

Comment: I have not been able to add pkexec to a keyboard shortcut... It simply doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu if You dont want enter your password any time use shortcut you can run this commands:

```
sudo visudo
```

This cause nano open in terminal.

In nano add `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` bottom of file replace username with your ubuntu username and save by `ctrl + o`.

After logout and login your sudo command wouldn't get password.

Notice:

> If you need security don't apply the change to your ubuntu. This will allow ANY person, cat or UFO alien that gets access to your system as you, via the network or keyboard, to execute commands as root, at any time.

Comment: This will allow ANY person, cat or UFO alien that gets access to your system as you, via the network or keyboard, to execute commands as `root`, at any time. This is probably a Bad Idea(tm). Also, reboot is not required. Logout/Login will suffice.

Comment: waltinator You're right.It's for crazy and lazy users.

Answer (score -2):

Put the sudo commands in the script on the lines you need privileges to run. Then run normally.

Comment: Have you ever tried this?  It will work when running from a terminal, but what about running from a shortcut, or from Alt-F2?  I don't think it will work.

Comment: @MartyFried Indeed, this will not work, since `sudo` needs to read password input from the command-line. This would only work in the specific situation where the commands being run with `sudo` are permitted (in the `sudoers` file) to be run without requiring password authentication.

Answer (score -3):

> This Only work for kde desktop.

If You dont want enter your password any time use shortcut you can Use this:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S <script>
```