# How to add gksudo or what to use instead in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, gksudo

I used to use `gksudo gedit /etc/something.conf` to edit system configuration files but this doesn't seem to work any more. Looks like there is no `gksudo` in `13.04`. How can I add it back or what am I intended to use instead?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, there is NO `gksudo` available for Ubuntu 13.04. It has been removed.
So, you can use 'sudo' instead. Just type: `sudo -i gedit /etc/something.conf`. You will be asked for your password.

If you are not comfortable with it, use this `sudo apt-get install gksu` to install gksu, and you can use the gksudo command.

Comment: I've heard using `sudo` for GUI programs is fundamentally wrong. Don't actually know why though.

Comment: You might like to read this http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6634/psa-gksu-is-no-longer-installed-by-default?cb=1

Comment: `sudo` can be bad as explained [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo) but `sudo -i` runs a shell as **root** so is always safe.

Comment: `gksu` package doesn't exist. Can use `pkexec` instead

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to thefourtheye's link I've found the answer and am sharing it here for further reference:

The package name is `gksu` so the answer to the actual question is

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

However, one should probably consider reading [PSA: gksu is no longer installed by default](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6634/psa-gksu-is-no-longer-installed-by-default) and [Why is gksu no longer installed by default in 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default-in-13-04) if interested in this question.

Comment: `gksu` package doesn't exist. Can use `pkexec` instead