# Is gksudo still in use, if not what is the replacment?

Tags: gksudo

Is gksudo still in use or is it officially removed? It is still available in the Ubuntu tutorial: (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting) and what would be the replacement for it?

Also what did the gk part stand for? Graphical?

Edit:

gksudo was ***Removed*** a replacment for it would be *sudo -i*

Comment: yes its still in use , just write gksudo in terminal.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: I am using OS X. I don't think that should be an issue, but i'm no expert. It says gksudo is an unrecognized command. Other threads I have come across said it was removed but may be reinstated.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/290810/how-to-add-gksudo-or-what-to-use-instead-in-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: Okay, so it's removal is indefinite. The tutorial should be fixed unless that is it's intent. Thanks for the help.

Comment: also read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo and http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default-in-13-04

Answer (score 0):

what does the `gk` part stand for:

gksu: Gtk+ Frontend to `su` and `sudo gksu` is a Gtk+ frontend to `/bin/su`. It supports login shells and preserving environment when acting as a `su` frontend. It is useful to menu items or other graphical programs that need to ask a user's password to run another program as another user. `gksu` can also act as a frontend to `sudo`. It installs a link `/usr/bin/` `gksudo`, which you can call to use this feature. When using `sudo`, `gksudo` respects `/etc/sudoers` definitions.<sup>[Linux Dictionary V 0.16](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Dictionary/html/index.html)</sup>