# How to edit read-only file in /etc?

Tags: permissions, users, vim, read-only

I'm a brand new user so I'm not sure of my way around the system yet. I want to change my computer's name, so I tried to edit the name in `/etc/hostname`, but it is a read-only file. Adding the `!` character didn't help. I'm using `vim` to edit the file.

Comment: How is tagMatcher's answer any better than http://askubuntu.com/a/92382/158442? There is literally nothing new. You can accept it if you want, but merging it is not needed.

Comment: Set the default output in the config file `sudo nano /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` and paste the following line



`[defaults]`
`# Human-readable output`
`stdout_callback = yaml`

https://www.shellhacks.com/ansible-human-readable-output-format/

Answer (score 38):

Changing system settings requires superuser permissions. From a terminal, do

```
sudo <editor> <filename>
```

where  could be vim or nano or any other editor command, and  is the one you need to edit.

You could also use`gksudo gedit <filename>`.

In either case you will be prompted for password of a user with superuser permissions - in a normal Ubuntu installation this would be the first user created during installation.

Comment: Read this, gksudo is removed? http://askubuntu.com/questions/290810/how-to-add-gksudo-or-what-to-use-instead-in-ubuntu-13-04/290817#290817

Comment: just checked - gksudo is available on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Thx you! Very helpful!

Comment: sudo vi <filename> when intending to use Vi.

Answer (score 19):

If you are editing a file without `sudo`, and you *need* `sudo` in order to save, simply use this vim command:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

Credit to [Dr Beco](https://superuser.com/questions/694450/using-vim-to-force-edit-a-file-when-you-opened-without-permissions). Note that vim will notice the file change and ask you if you want to **(L)oad** the changes, press <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: thanks! this works even when the file's permissions are 400 or 440, with no one having write permission!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, running as sudo or even logged in as root. I get a message "Read-only file system" when I try this, and "Shel returned 1", with no change and no ability to save the file. -----EDIT: indeed, this can't be done when you're in a read-only filesystem (my example was an app installed with snap; I was trying to modify the .desktop file). However, there are alternative locations for the .desktop files, e.g: /var/lib/snap/desktop/applications

Answer (score 8):

#### Very Short Answer:

You **can** modify a file (even if it's read-only) if you **own** it.

#### Short Answer:

Even if the user which you are logged in as (in this case `navid`) has administrative privileges, you won't be able to modify `/etc/hostname`, because the `root` user owns that file. Consequently, you should log in as the root user.

#### Long Answer

Assuming that you want to change your computer name from `oldName` to `newName`, here are the steps that you should follow:

1. Log in as the root user:

   ```
   navid@oldName:~$ sudo su -
   ```
2. Open hostname:

   ```
   root@oldName:~# vi /etc/hostname
   ```
3. You will see `oldName`. Press <kbd>i</kbd> to go to the insert mode then change it to `newName`. Then press  <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit.
4. Open hosts:

   ```
   root@oldName:~# vi /etc/hosts
   ```

   The top 2 lines look like this:

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   127.0.1.1       oldName
   ```
5. Similarly to what you did in step 3, change the computer name from `oldName` to `newName`. Then save and exit.
6. Exit the root user:

   ```
   root@oldName:~# exit
   ```
7. Save all of your unsaved work and restart your computer:

   ```
   navid@oldName:~$ reboot
   ```
8. Open your terminal, and you will see that your computer name has successfully been changed! :-)

   ```
   navid@newName:~$
   ```

**Note:** Although you may achieve what you want by skipping steps 4 and 5, I strongly recommend doing them as well, to avoid potential errors in the future.

See also:

- [Why can I modify a read-only file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815838/why-can-i-modify-a-read-only-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -H gedit <path to file>
```

eg :

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/environment
```

or
`sudo nano /etc/environment`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> and hit Enter(for nano)

Answer (score -1):

You might not have access to the file to change it.

In order to get access you need to get super user privileges and that is `sudo`.

Open terminal, type:

```
sudo -H gedit "your file name "
```

If you use any other text editor type that in.

Answer (score -3):

By default you have wight permission to hosts file to root user only, as shown below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 252 Dec 16 08:40 /etc/hosts
```

Hence you have to use sudo to edit this or else you can use below command to become root

```
sudo su -
```

**however this is not recommended at all.**

safest and recommended it you use below command to edit the file

> sudo vim /etc/hosts

then press "**Esc**" on keyboard and then type "**:w!**" to write the changes to the hosts file then agin type "**:q**" or "**:q!**", this should shall do the trick for you.