# disk space used up

Tags: disk, disk-usage

I have upgraded to 13.04 and lose disk space, ...
I have a 3 TB hard disk, and had yesterday still 890 GB free, ... today all is gone!

Disk Usage Analyzer does not give me a clue and says that it could not read all directories due to missing permission.
How can I start it as root, believing that this would give me all permissions.

Log files don't show me also anything useful for that matter.

Comment: give us the output of `lsblk `

Answer (score 78):

To run a graphical application as root, you would use the commands `gksu` or `gksudo`. However, these have been removed from Ubuntu 13.04 [for various reasons](https://askubuntu.com/q/284306/52726).

So, in order to run Disk Usage Analyzer as root, here are two methods:

#### Method 1

1. Open a terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Type `sudo apt-get install gksu`, this will install `gksu` and `gksudo`.
2. To run **Disk Usage Analyzer** as root, do the following command:

   `gksudo baobab`

#### Method 2

1. Open a terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Type `sudo -i`. This will log you in as root in the terminal.
2. Run **Disk Usage Analyzer** by typing:

   `baobab`

In both cases, don't close the terminal until you are done, because closing the terminal will also close Disk Usage Analyzer.

Further to your problem, you can use the command `df -h` to show you the sizes of your partitions and see how much space is available.

Comment: I cannot install any program, since ZERO bytes are free!!! second way worked, but I have no idea how to figure out what to do next. I cannot figure out who fills up my harddisk and how to stop it, ...
any hints????

Comment: Mount all of your partitions, and look at the output of Disk Usage Analyzer. Sort it by size. See which folders have used up the space, and which folders looks suspicious. You know your computer best. I doubt 890GBs can be used up just like that. Where was this 890GB space? Was it a separate partition? Unallocated space? Part of another partition? Part of the Ubuntu partition? Edit your question to include the output of `df -h` and `sudo parted -l`.

Comment: I found something: in my home directory was a file .xsession-errors, with 1,357 GB !!!!  tail of this PM Authentication deferred - ignoring client message
I used cp /dev/null .xsession-errors  to clear it
It starts immediately to fill it up with the same error!!
How can I fix that?

Comment: On Ubuntu MATE 20.04, it's not `baobab`, but `mate-disk-usage-analyzer`.

Comment: Method 2 worked flawlessly. Such a big difference running Disk Analyzer with and without sudo.

Answer (score 16):

### `baobab` Disk Usage Analyzer GUI, and `ncdu` GUI-like command-line tool

*Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04.*

Running the Disk Usage Analyzer as root can be done from the terminal simply with this:

```bash
sudo baobab
```

Additionally, you can use a command-line tool which works very well, called `ncdu`. It's very intuitive and easy to use. Once it's running, use the arrow keys to navigate around your file system and drill down into folders of interest which show large disk usage. This is a command-line tool, but GUI-like in its nature. Run it with:

```bash
sudo ncdu
```

`sudo` may not even be required for it. For a help menu while in ncdu, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd>.

Note that I believe ncdu stands for "ncurses Disk Usage", where ncurses is the library or tool that makes an interactive, graphics-like interface possible in the terminal. (See [my `ncurses` getting started info. in C here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master/c/ncurses#about)).

`ncdu` is a truly wonderful, fast, and very easy-to-use tool. I love it can easily be used over ssh sessions too. It is my "go-to" tool whenever I need to quickly analyze disk space usage, whether on my local machine or remoted into another machine.

The `baobab` Disk Usage Analyzer GUI tool is my secondary tool. I use it only rarely when I need to see more insight all at once, rather than drilling down manually into large folders with `ncdu`.

### Other, related tools

1. To quickly see your disk and partition usage, run:

   ```bash
   df -h
   ```

   Look especially for the row where the far right column, which is the "Mounted on" column, has just a `/` in it. This is your root directory. You'll be able to quickly see how much disk space overall is used and available in your root dir. To quickly focus on and highlight *just* this line, run:

   ```bash
   df -h | grep -B 1000 -A 1000 '.*/$'
   ```
2. To quickly see individual file and folder usage for *just the one folder you are in now*, run:

   ```bash
   du -h
   ```

   To see just the last line, which is the sum-total of everything in your current folder, run:

   ```bash
   du -sh
   ```

   The `-s` says to 's'ummarize, which means to just output the last line. That output is **exactly identical** to what you get with `du -h | tail -n 1`.

### References:

1. I've previously documented all of this to myself in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo in this file here: [git & Linux cmds, help, tips & tricks - Gabriel.txt](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/git%20%26%20Linux%20cmds%2C%20help%2C%20tips%20%26%20tricks%20-%20Gabriel.txt). For more information, search that document for the above commands.

<sub>Keywords: see and analyze disk usage and disk space in Linux Ubuntu</sub>