# In 'sudo gedit' I can not use Ctrl Space to activate fcitx input method

Tags: input-method

In 'sudo gedit' I can not use Ctrl Space to activate fcitx input method.

I can activate fcitx with Ctrl Space as normal user.

I use ubuntu12.04.2 amd64 arch.

How to do with it ?

Thanks

Comment: Is `gksudo gedit` broken as well? ([explained](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo))

Comment: I can run `gksudo gedit` successfully, but can not activate `fcitx` in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check: https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/FAQ#Root_application_under_normal_user_X

Root application in general cannot communicate with user application by user session dbus, but xim only has the restriction of things need to be run under same X.

BTW, X application is in general broken with sudo, it's highly recommended not to do that.

Comment: Good answer (upvoted it), but your last comment is outdated, please read http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default-in-13-04

Comment: What I mean broken, is not ubuntu specific nor from the point of view that either su, sudo is used. DBus is so widely used, and see my reply before, no matter you're using sudo/su/etc, application cannot connect to user dbus, which mean quite a lot function is not working.

For example, if you're using media player, and use mpris(a user session dbus protocol) to control this player, if thsi media player is running as root user, your controller will not be able to control it. And your root application will not find gnome-settings-daemon, and similar things will happen to many app.

Comment: Hahaha...Linux community now tends to explain its deficit as some philosophy.