# sudo does not work in GUI after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: unity, upgrade, sudo, 13.10

On 2 completely different machines I have the same problem after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10:
All programs/task requiering sudo permissions (software updater, starting synaptic, installing programs, shutdown) do not start / execute. No gksu (or other) window comes up. Synaptic never shows, software updater pops up with a "you are not allowed to perform this action" message.

All programs / task work when started from terminal with sudo, like "sudo synaptics" asks for my password, starts and works as expected.

I am in the admin group which is liked in sudoers config (verified with visudo and getent group admin).

Some link from GUI to gksu (or similar) is broken.

Comment: **gksu** is not installed by default in 13.04 or 13.10 see this question [Why is gksu no longer installed by default in 13.04?](http://askubuntu.com/q/284306/107450).  But you can install it and its working for me in 13.10

Comment: The problem is likely polkit. Can you edit your question and add the following: `dpkg -l *policykit*`. Do not use comments for adding information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/1240336/comments/19

```
sudo pam-auth-update --force
```

Comment: At least on 14.10, make sure "[*] Register user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy" is selected in the dialog. After running the command, reboot the system.