# Cannot start nautilus or any other app via gksu anymore

Tags: 14.04, gksudo

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on my Dell XPS 13 laptop, and up until now I was able to start nautilus via terminal or by using ALT+F2 and typing `gksu nautilus` through Dash. Only now, supposedly after I upgraded the system via update manager where unity package got updated, I cannot do it anymore. When trying to launch it via ALT+F2 I can see a cogwheel moving instead of a cursor, and if I do it with terminal `gksu nautilus` it shows me this

```
gksu nautilus
** (gksu:6420): CRITICAL **: fcntl error
** (gksu:6420): WARNING **: Lock taken by pid: -1. Exiting.
```

if I launch it with `sudo` command, everything works as expected.

The question is, is it a bug (which means I will report it immediately), or is it a known issue and there is a workaround I can try already?

Thanks!

Comment: gksu has been depreciated, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default for a discussion. I am not sure where that leaves you. You can try filing a bug report, but I suspect it will be closed as "won't fix"

Answer (score 1):

Try to do `rm ~/.gksu.lock` it's safe to remove that file, it will be recreated when you be successful at doing gksu again.