# Is there a better command to use than Sudo?

Tags: sudo, gksudo

I used to hear you are supposed to use gksudo, but that is no longer installed by default. What should be used in its stead?

Comment: kindly see http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Ubuntu 14.04, and you want to avoid the command line, otherwise sudo works fine.
I believe your answer is [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/ubuntu-14-04-add-open-as-rootadministrator-to-context-menu/) which is a "open as admin" right-click context menu.