# How to open a file outside of the home folder using sudo

Tags: command-line

I recently had an error with cinnamon desktop environment that I know how to fix. There is just one stupid obstacle in my way, when I try to use

```
sudo gedit var/lib/dpkg/status
```

to go to that folder it takes me to home/var/lib/dpkg/status (not even a folder I have made?) and opens a text document named status with gedit. I need to open computer/var/lib/dpkg/status. This looks and sounds like a stupid thing to me, it probably is, can you even do this? If you can, please tell me how. Also, if this is a duplicate (I don't think anyone else is as stupid as me) please link me the op. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to fixing the path as kos pointed out, you should use `gksudo` instead of `sudo` when opening a program that uses a graphical interface. See [What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

Comment: Well ... gksu is depreciated see http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default/284717#284717 and https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gksu/+question/227275

Comment: If you don't have `gksu`/`gksudo`, [you can use `sudo -H`](https://askubuntu.com/a/270019/22949) or `sudo -i` instead to run a graphical application as root (and still avoid the problems with plain `sudo`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By omitting `/` at the start of the path you are specifying a relative path, but you want to specify an absolute path:

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Also, please use `gksudo` for graphical applications. `sudo` isn't really fit for that. Like this:

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

See [What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”?](/q/11760).

Comment: I thought it would be something stupid like that, thanks for that. Also I didn't know the difference between sudo and gksudo.