# Give user password in terminal through argument

Tags: command-line, python, python-2.7

I have created a python application in my Ubuntu machine which run commands to terminal. I would like when the program start to continue running as root. I know that to get a root terminal we use the following command:

```
sudo -i
```

then the shell ask us to type our pass and when we do it we have root for that terminal season until we type

```
exit
```

But can I set the pass parameter though a argument ? So the terminal won't prompt a 'give a pass' line?
Another question is when I use a live usb and I want to run `sudo -i` to get root privileges do I need to type a pass or not?

Comment: It's a bad idea to pass passwords with command-line arguments. Command-lines arguments can be seen from un-priviledges users eg. with the ps command and will be logged in your bash-history. Both are things you should avoid.

Comment: @MadMike ok but can a window be prompt with `sudo -i`  command? Cause I don't get any window when I run the command in my python program. And what happens when I use live Ubuntu? Can I use `sudo -i` wihout pass?

Comment: You will get a graphical password prompt when you use gksu instead of sudo. I'm not sure how to start a terminal session with root-privileges with gksu.

Comment: @MadMike but `gksu` isn not installed and I need to use the python script in all ubuntu machines either they have or not `gksu`. If I have a live cd then can just use `sudo -i` ? As this question say (http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply start your command with `sudo` rights:

```
sudo your_python_script
```

And **NEVER** use your password in a parameter.

Comment: ok when I use live usb and want to run my script the sudo command won't ask for password, will it?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I've never tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't know whether the logic is correct with my option, but it certainly works.

First you create a `rsa pub` key using the command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then copy and append the pub key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` of `root` by using the command:

```
ssh-copy-id root@<your ip>
```

After that when you try `ssh root@<your ip>`, it won't prompt for the root password and you will be able to get root prompt.

For example, if you want to run a shell script, `run.sh` in `/opt` directory as root, from your login without prompting password try this:

```
ssh -X root@<your ip> "sh /opt/run.sh"
```

'-X' option is used to set `$DISPLAY` for root.

Hope this idea helps.