# How can I move files from my pen-drive to a directory present in / using GUI?

Tags: files

How can I move files from my pen-drive to the `/personal` folder using the graphical interface in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Can I shift my `/personal` folder to anywhere from `/` ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us the error message you are receiving when trying to copy & paste the files (if any).

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want those files on your system partition yet outside of your home directory? That's where you store “personal” files normally. So unless you want to install software system-wide or change the system configuration there should be no need for that.

Answer (score 1):

`root` is owner of `/`, so that means you need to use `sudo` to get rights for copying into `/`.

Since you want to do it in graphical interface, you need to open-up Nautilus from terminal:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Answer (score 0):

The utility `gksudo` is useful in this case and is still available to Ubuntu even if no longer installed *by default*. Install it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

And then you can open Nautilus with elevated privileges and copy as you see fit:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

**Note:**

Ubuntu users are not usually actively encouraged to use graphical applications with *elevated privileges* as the potential to harm the system is great. Use caution...

**References:**

- [Why is gksu no longer installed by default?](https://askubuntu.com/q/284306/57576)
- [What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/11760/57576)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it for graphical purpose than firstly you should change permission of **/Personal** directory afterthat you will be able to copy-paste by graphical mode.

sudo chmod 755 /Personal