# gksudo command doesnt run

Tags: matlab, gksudo

I'm trying to install Matlab on my Ubuntu 16 . I mounted the iso file and go to directory then run the command  `gksudo ./install` and typed the password ,but the installer doesn't start. When I'm using only `./install` , installer starts , but can't make a folder for the installation files. It gives me:

```
(java:25127): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'gtk-ok' for stock: Unable to load image-loading module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so: /tmp/mathworks_25097/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: gksudo is probably not installed. I'm not sure why you would need it to run a script in the terminal - just use `sudo ./install`

Comment: duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default

Comment: when I use sudo ./install it gives me
sudo: ./install: command not found

Comment: I also tried fur to type sudo -i and then
./install but also doesnt work ... it only works when I type just ./install without any sudo but so I dont get the privileges

Comment: I have already seen the other article and it didnt help me ...

Comment: `Gtk-WARNING ` are NOT an issue. They can be ignored.

Comment: "when I use sudo ./install it gives me sudo: ./install: command not found" that usually means the script has no execute permission... weird. can you show us `ls -l install` in the directory