# gedit shortcuts

Tags: shortcuts, gedit

Is there a way to make my own shortcuts for terminal in gedit?

I mean, for example if I want to compile a C++ source, when I press F9 I want it to make  `g++ source_file.cpp` (this is only an example)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the command itself, you can use aliases.

Edit `~/.bash_aliases` and add your alias like this:

`alias foobar="g++ /location/of/file/file.cpp"`
Where foobar is the name of the custom command.

Then do `. ~/.bash_aliases` to reload the file.

As far as the hotkey part, I'll come back and add to my answer if I figure anything out about that, or hopefully someone else will know.

EDIT: Here is the full answer to your question (as best I can tell): [Custom keyboard shortcut to lauch a terminal and run a command in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116052/custom-keyboard-shortcut-to-lauch-a-terminal-and-run-a-command-in-unity). It looks like it renders the alias section void, but I will leave it there.

EDIT2: Via http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-433538.html, check out gedit external tools: https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/ExternalTools. This will give you a variable for your current file name for use in the command.

Comment: Ok, this is good, but, I actually want something else. For example, if I have in gedit one opened file, named FILE, I want to press F9 and I want it to compile my file.. for example   g++ FILE. In VIM I know you have the '%' , but in gedit I can't find nothing :(. Anyway, thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Think I have an answer for you. Edited it in!!