# How to run sudo .sh file after wakeup : Touchpad disabled after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: suspend, touchpad, 17.10, wakeup

I faced a small issue after an upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10. My touchpad started to disable after my system wakes up from suspend mode. I tried this temporary method and works for me:

1. Create touchpad_wakeup.sh file in your home directory.

Its content is:

```
sudo rmmod i2c_hid
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

2. So next time when my system wakesup: I login my username and password, then open terminal window using the shortcut key Ctrl+Alt+T

Write the following:

```
sudo bash ./touchpad_wakeup.sh
```

3. Press enter

My touchpad starts working. I want to add this to wakeup sequence (`/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`), but didn't have much success to automate this.

Comment: Please don't use HTML in the formatting of your question, it makes editing very time consuming.  Use the controls at the top of the Text Edit dialog instead, or use markdown.

Comment: While not exactly 100% automation that you wanted, you may want to try this. You can place the sh file in your home directory, associate a keyboard shortcut with the terminal command- `./touchpad_wakeup.sh`. So you can run that file with keyboard shortcut. See this answer on how to do this https://askubuntu.com/a/116110

Answer (score 2):

To automate the call to your script on wakeup, you can add it under `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` instead of `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`

Here is what I've done:

- `sudo touch /lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpadwakeup`
- Put the following content:

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> case $1 in
>   post)
>     rmmod i2c_hid
>     modprobe i2c_hid
>     ;;
> esac
> ```

- `sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpadwakeup`

It works fine but I hope we'll have a cleaner solution (e.g, a patch) in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

There is discussion and another one solution of this bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1723799) (
in three words: use [upstream kernel 4.13.7-041307-generic](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13.7/) )

BTW, could you push "This bug affects me" green link on that page, so developers fix it faster. It's really annoying to reload kernel module every time after suspend.