# Ubuntu 17.10: Lid closing disables touchpad, how to fix?

Tags: suspend, touchpad, 17.10

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on a Dell Vostro 3559.

I've noticed that when I close the lid on my computer, it seems not only to go into a strange suspend, but also to disable my touchpad.
The strange thing is that the touchpad works fine when I suspend through the power menu. It seems to do something different when I close my lid.

I haven't been able to find the settings in either Tweaks or normal Settings where I decide what it does on lid close.

[How to run sudo .sh file after wakeup : Touchpad disabled after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968790/how-to-run-sudo-sh-file-after-wakeup-touchpad-disabled-after-upgrading-to-ubu) seems to be onto a temporary fix for the problem, the two commands make the touchpad work again, but I'd rather just set the computer to suspend normally on lid close.

Does anyone know how this is done?

---

EDIT: Switched to xorg, and now it works fine. Seems to be a Wayland specific problem.

Comment: Read `man pm-action`, or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man8/pm-action.8.html to see what happens whan you close the lid. There are places you could intervene, and run your fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a kernel bug.
As reported by Askar Timirgazin in [How to run sudo .sh file after wakeup : Touchpad disabled after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968790/how-to-run-sudo-sh-file-after-wakeup-touchpad-disabled-after-upgrading-to-ubu), the bug was fixed by updating the kernel to 4.13.7.

TL;DR

Download the following kernel updates.

---

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13.7/linux-headers-4.13.7-041307_4.13.7-041307.201711060248_all.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13.7/linux-headers-4.13.7-041307-generic_4.13.7-041307.201711060248_amd64.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13.7/linux-image-4.13.7-041307-generic_4.13.7-041307.201711060248_amd64.deb

---

Install them with `dpkg -i`

Run `sudo reboot`

You should be able to use your mousepad.

Sources:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13.7/

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1723799

Answer (score 0):

How to switch to Xorg:
[How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)