# Ubuntu 16.04 touchpad not working after closing laptop lid

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, laptop

Every time I close my laptop's lid, and open it later, touchpad stops working and I can't make it work otherwise, but only by rebooting. I have also downloaded `touchpad-indicator` software, and disabling/enabling touchpad through it, but it didn't help also.

Mouse works fine, even when this happens, but not touchpad. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the same issue discussed here: [Ubuntu 17.10: Lid closing disables touchpad, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969156/ubuntu-17-10-lid-closing-disables-touchpad-how-to-fix?rq=1)

If so, upgrading to a newer Ubuntu version should fix it. Ubuntu 16.04 is quite old now, why not go with 19.04?

Comment: Same problem on 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution from [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2373653): Removing `psmouse` module and readding it:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help changing from wayland to xorg: [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10). (Originally proposed by Joe: [Ubuntu 17.10: Lid closing disables touchpad, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969156/ubuntu-17-10-lid-closing-disables-touchpad-how-to-fix/978075#978075)) It worked for me on 22.04 LTS.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1257050)