# Touchpad stops responding after closing laptop lid

Tags: xinput, libinput

I recently installed ubuntu 18.0.4 on my new laptop and the touchpad stops responding after closing the lid.

The device name is SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:CD41 Touchpad
The device driver is xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 0.28.1-1~18.04.1 amd64

I tried installing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics, but that prevented the touchpad from working altogether.

I also tried disabling and re-enabling the touchpad using xinput commands but that doesn't fix the issue either.

From `/proc/bus/input/devices`

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=cd41 Version=0100
N: Name="SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:CD41 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-SYNA7DB5:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-SYNA7DB5:00/0018:06CB:CD41.0005/input/input20
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event9 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: On my laptop I have an Alt-F7 _feature_ that allows me to turn the touchpad on and off. Maybe you have such too? I would think that the OS is responsible for the feature, but if the laptop itself is, then maybe that's what's happening?

Comment: I checked and I have the same feature.  However, this doesn't fix my issue unfortunately.

Comment: The next time it happens again, please run `evemu-record` *(it's part of `evemu-tools` package)*. It would enumerate input devices, and ask which one do you want to listen on. Reply with the number that corresponds to your touchpad. Then try to use the touchpad. If you see no output in the `evemu-record`, then you know something's up with the touchpad driver, you'd need to try more recent kernel.

Comment: Thanks, Hi-Angel.  evemu-record shows no input from the touchpad after closing and re-opening the lid.  I changed my kernel from 5.0.0.37 to 5.0.0.23 and I'm not seeing the issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.(Acer HELIOS 300)

My device is same `SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:CD41 Touchpad`, after closing the lid, after a few minutes or suspend. Touchpad stops working. Restart solves it but again happens.

My input from `/proc/bus/input/devices`

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=cd41 Version=0100
N: Name="SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:CD41 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-SYNA7DB5:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-9/i2c-SYNA7DB5:00/0018:06CB:CD41.0005/input/input34
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event17 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

I searched around and found this [website](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1442699),
where the comment 22 having to command :

```
$ sudo rmmod i2c_hid
$ sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

after running these commands the touchpad starts working again (temporarily).
But after the next closing lid, the issue starts again

Comment: How is this an answer? You have the same problem, so what is the point of posting this ? It should be deleted soon.

Comment: @Pilot6 they suggested a workaround —  reloading `i2c_hid` module. It's an answer.

Comment: @Armab could you please try to update [to latest mainline kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade), and see if it solves the issue?

Comment: I have the same exact hardware - the commands you suggested also work for me.  I've since changed kernel version from 5.0.0.37 to 5.0.0.23 (they were both installed by default in my case) and I don't have the problem anymore.

Comment: For now I have installed the latest kernal 5.4.2 using the tool ukuu. And I dont have the touchpad issue. Seems like kernal is doing something with it. Newer kernal dont have this problem

Comment: @ArnabGoswami great! Looks like a bug in an older kernel. You might want to update your answer to mention that upgrading the kernel fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make a comment, but my reputation is not enough (less than 50).

I have the same issue, and kernel is 5.3.0-18-generic.

Reloading `i2c_hid` works, so I use the method provided here: >[How to run sudo .sh file after wakeup : Touchpad disabled after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968790/how-to-run-sudo-sh-file-after-wakeup-touchpad-disabled-after-upgrading-to-ubu)