# Touchpad stops working at reboot. Module missing

Tags: 18.04, kernel, touchpad

I have Dell Inspiron 7591 installed with dual boot Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and Windows 10.

On installation touchpad was not working. The module i2c_hid seemed missing. When the module was loaded, touchpad started working fine. Although the module needs to be re-loaded every time after the reboot. Is there any way that the touchpad stays functioning without manually loading the module?

I tried [Myx](https://askubuntu.com/a/972479/1115341)'s answer. It didn't work.

Feel free to ask for any required details.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854896/comments/16) solution. This will fix touchpad issue on dell

Answer (score 0):

You may try "modprobe i2c_hid_acpi". This Tip comes from the Fujitsu Laptop community. Make it a systemd service !

Actually my Fujitsu E 5511 Lifebook E5511MF5BMDE needs this help only for touchpad. Works fine now. Tested with Ubuntu 22.04beta and 20.04.4LTS.

My older E5510 needed "modprobe i2c_hid" to do anything with input. Make it a systemd service ! Fujitsu E Laptops rock. ELAN does not always ...